# Definition of a ray?

Tags: optics, electromagnetic-radiation, terminology, geometric-optics

The typical definition of a [ray](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ray_%28optics%29) and the one that I was initially taught was that a ray was a line perpendicular to the wave front. However, when reading up on birefringence it seems as though there are cases where the 'ray' itself is not perpendicular to the wave front (although the wave vector $\vec k$ is). So given this, how do we define a ray and what determines the direction it point??

(If I was to take a guess I would say it had something to do with the Poynting vector)

Comment: This is pretty hard to answer without a reference to the source where the contradiction came up in.

Comment: @EmilioPisanty I can't exactly remember. I came across it a while back. I will have a look to see I can find it.

Comment: I assume you are concerned with situations where the Poynting vector is not aligned with the group velocity and/or the group and phase velocities are not parallel?  Both of these situations can and do occur, but generally the ray would be defined by the direction of the group velocity I believe...  Would need to check that to be sure.  Look at Whitham's book on nonlinear waves or Stix's book on waves in plasmas.  Both have long discussions on this topic.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just found this source (1) which explains that rays are curves such that the direction a ray points is the same as that of the Poynting vector at a given point.

**References**

(1) p110 of '[Microwave Antenna Theory and Design](https://books.google.co.uk/books?id=Aex6dlKreHEC&source=gbs_navlinks_s)' by S.Silver  (link to google books)

Answer (score 0):

I don't think there is a really strict definition of a ray. I would say that a reasonable definition is:

1. electromagnetic energy density is confined to a finite area (e.g. gauss beam and not plane wave) in the transversal plane
2. The Poynting vectors are reasonably parallel in this plane. (e.g. gauss beam and not spherical wave)

The direction the ray moves or points is given by the poynting vector, simply because this is the direction of energy flow, which we normally care about.